# Poor Performance at Low Battery

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, battery, performance

I'm having an issue where my phone gets sluggish and non-responsive when the battery level gets to around 35% or less.  Apps will freeze, it will take the keyboard a long time to appear, and the unlock pattern will sometimes not show up at all when turning the screen on.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Phone - Galaxy S3

Carrier - Sprint

Android version - 4.3

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using stock Samsung firmware. If so, probably you enabled Samsung's "power saving mode".

Go to "power saving mode" settings and unchecked "CPU power saving" options.

Comment: I double-checked and the power saving mode has never been turned on.

Comment: Do you have a rooted SGS3? Also are is it installed any battery/power savings app?

Comment: It is a stock SGS3 without any power saving applications (ZDBox is installed but the power save feature is turned off, I'll disable the battery service entirely just to be safe).  Perhaps I should just try a full backup and factory reset?